# Colour masking with Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

Before an alpha colour channel existed sprites in games often had a mask colour, which was a predefined value that wouldn't be displayed. Many spritesheets have an arbitrary background colour, which I want to be able to mask using Javascript canvas.

So far I haven't been able to find a way to do this in the documentation and when I search for colour masking the results seem to relate to clipping an image with a stencil image or SVG, which is not what I'm after.

One way I could do achieve what I want to do is by reading each pixel value, checking the RGB value and if it matches set the alpha for that pixel to 0. The problem with that approach is that it would be unbearably slow in Javascript. What would be a faster/better way to mask a specific colour on an image?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and best way is to use an image format that does support transparency like *webp* or *png*.

Assets should be prepared only once by dedicated tools, not every time someone will use your app.